# Access a variable in an object from an encapsulate one

Tags: javascript

The title is a little ambigous but the code explains the issue very clearly:

```
function Game() {
    this.secret = '';
    this.Playground = {
        this.someTreat: function() {
            console.log('how to access secret from here ?');
        }
    };
}

var Test = new Game();
Test.Playground.someTreat();
```

I provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gzSt5/4/) with this same code.

Comment: This code is both syntactically invalid and different from what's in the JSFiddle. Please decide on what question you're asking _before_ you post.

Comment: Yes i just saw a syntaxical error and you posted between my jsfiddle and stackoverflow updates.

Comment: You still haven't fixed it, though.

Comment: The line `this.someTreat: function() {` is invalid; it should be a `=` not a `:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you need to make some changes to how you access the variable `secret` - you could do it by copying the `this` keyword into a `that` variable like Peter's answer.

Another way could be like this:

```
function Game() {
  var secret = 'secret information';
  this.Playground = {
    this.someTreat = function() {
        console.log(secret);
    };
  };
}
```

Because of the `Game` function enclosure the secret variable is private to that scope. And as long as you define your functions within that enclosure, those functions will have access to the secret "private" variable.

Comment: This also has the consequence that `secret` is not a property of all `Game` objects, which is fine and might even be what you would expect from a name like `secret`, but it's worth noting.

Comment: This would be my preferred solution as long as `secret` didn't need to be publicly accessible (which I'm guessing it doesn't based on the name) and as long as there was no anticipated need for a subclass of `Game` that would also need to access `secret`.

Comment: You could even do both things at once with `var secret = this.secret = 'secret information';`

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create a copy of `this` in the `Game` function. The canonical thing to do is make a variable called `that`.

```
function Game() {
    this.secret = 'secret information';
    var that = this;
    this.Playground = {
        someTreat: function() {
            console.log(that.secret);
        }
    };
}
var test = new Game();
test.Playground.someTreat();
```

You can [see this in action on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HcMk5/).

Comment: "canonical"? Geez, whatever happened to "best practice"? ;-p Both are buz words that can be replaced by a variant of "common".

Answer (score 0):

(I fixed your error in the definition of Playground and someTreat)

use a closure on 'this':

```
function Game() {
    var self = this;
    this.secret = 'xyz';
    this.Playground = {
        someTreat: function() {
            console.log('how to access secret from here ?');
            console.log('response: use self');
            console.log('self.secret: ' + self.secret);
        }
    };
}
```